# Is it possible to write "let go" without a noun?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to know if it's possible to use "let go already" as in "release something or somebody" without actually having to write a noun (or pronoun).

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Saying [already](https://www.lexico.com/definition/already) like that is AmE usage but not BrE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "let go" is intransitive, and doesn't need an object. "Let go" is an acceptable shortened version of "let go of it" or similar phrases.